# I thought *.DDS files were meant to be quick to load?

Tags: compression, directx, textures, directdraw, dds-format

Ok, so I'm trying to weigh up the pro's and con's of using various different texture compression techniques. I spend 99.999% of my time coding 2D sprite games for Windows machines using DirectX.

So far I have looked at texture packing (SpriteSheets) with alpha-trimming and that seems like a decent way to get a bit more performance. Now I am starting to look at the texture format that they are stored in; currently everything is stored as *.PNGs.

I have heard that *.DDS files are good, especially when used with DXT5 (/3/1 depending on the task) compression as the texture remains compressed in VRAM? Also people say that as they are already DirectDraw Surfaces they load in much, much quicker too.

So I created an application to test this out; I call the line below 20 times, releasing the texture between each call.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
 {
  if( FAILED( D3DXCreateTextureFromFile( g_pd3dDevice, L"Test.dds", &g_pTexture ) ) )
  {
   return E_FAIL;
  }

  g_pTexture->Release();
  g_pTexture = NULL;
 }
```

Now if I try this with a DXT5 texture, it takes 5x longer to complete than with loading in a simple *.PNG. I've heard that if you don't generate Mipmaps it can go slower, so I double checked that. Then I changed the program that I was using to generate the *.DDS file, switching to NVIDIA's own nvcompress.exe, but none of it had any effect.

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that the files (both *.png and *.dds) are both the same image, just saved in different formats. (Same size, amount of alpha, everything!)

**EDIT 2:** When using the following parameters it loads in almost 2.5x faster AND consumes a LOT less VRAM!

```
 D3DXCreateTextureFromFileEx( g_pd3dDevice, L"Test.dds", D3DX_DEFAULT_NONPOW2, D3DX_DEFAULT_NONPOW2, D3DX_FROM_FILE, 0, D3DFMT_FROM_FILE, D3DPOOL_MANAGED, D3DX_FILTER_NONE, D3DX_FILTER_NONE, 0, NULL, NULL, &g_pTexture )
```

However, I'm now losing all my transparency in the texture, I've looked at the DXT5 texture and it looks fine in Paint.NET and DirectX DDS Viewer. However when loaded in all the transparency turns to solid black. ColorKey issue?

**EDIT 3:** Ignore that last bit, I was being idiotic and in my "quick example" haste I'd forgotten to enable Alpha-Blending on the D3DXSprite->Begin(). Doh!

Comment: maybe the texture is copied to video memory (very slow), so you're not only measuring load time of the texture itself

Comment: Question about EDIT2: "almost 2.5x faster" than the original 5x slower, or 2.5x faster than PNG?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to distinguish between the format that your files are stored in on disk and the format that the textures ultimately use in video memory. DXT compressed textures offer a good balance between memory usage and quality in video memory but other compression techniques like PNG or Jpeg compression generally result in smaller files and/or better quality on disk.

DDS files have the advantage that they support DXT formats directly and are laid out on disk in the same way that DirectX expects the data to be laid out in memory so there is minimal CPU time required after they are loaded to convert them into a format the hardware can use. They also support pre-generated mipmap chains which formats like PNG do not support. Compressing an image to DXT formats is a fairly time consuming process so you generally want to avoid doing it on load if possible.

A DDS file with pre-generated mipmaps that is the same size as and uses the same format as the video memory texture you plan to create from it will use the least CPU time of any standard format. You need to make sure you tell D3DX not to perform any scaling, filtering, format conversion or mipmap generation to guarantee that though. `D3DXCreateTextureFromFileEx` allows you to specify flags that prevent any internal conversions happening (`D3DX_DEFAULT_NONPOW2` for image width and height if your hardware supports non power of two textures, `D3DFMT_FROM_FILE` to prevent mipmap generation or format conversion, `D3DX_FILTER_NONE` to prevent any filtering or scaling).

CPU time is only half the story though. These days CPUs are pretty fast and hard drives are relatively slow so sometimes your total load time can be shorter if you load a smaller compressed file format like PNG or JPG and then do lots of CPU work to convert it than if you load a larger file like a DDS and just do a memcpy into video memory. A common approach that gives good results is to zip DDS files and decompress them for fast loading from disk and minimal CPU cost for format conversion.

Compression formats like PNG and JPG will compress some images more effectively than others. DDS is a fixed compression ratio - a given image resolution and format will always compress to the same size (this is why it is more suitable for decompression in hardware). If you're using simple non-representative images for testing (e.g. a uniform colour or simple pattern) then your PNG file is likely to be very small and so will load from disk faster than a typical game image would.

Comment: Thanks matt, brilliant answer there. I've edited my original post with a related issue.

Answer (score 1):

Compare loading a standard PNG and then compressing it to the time it takes to load a DDS file.

Still I can't see why a PNG would load any faster than the same texture DXT5 compressed.  For one it will be a fair bit smaller so it should load form disk faster! Is this DXt5 texture the same as the PNG texture?  ie are they the same size?

Have you tried playing with D3DXCreateTextureFromFileEx?  You have far more control over what is going on.  It may help you out.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned what files were being loaded.. Edited it now to reflect that.

Comment: any chance of seeing those textures?

Comment: Can do if neeeded, but they are standard multiple of four sized texture sprite sheet containing an animated image.